# 16.04 - How big should I provide for each partition?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, ssd, home-directory, boot-partition

I have a 250GB SSD & a 1TB HDD on my Lenovo Z40. I'm thinking of putting my boot files & some apps on my SSD, & all of my files + some apps would be on HDD.
I'm wondering how big I should allocate for each mount point.

Answer (score 0):

From lsblk:

## sda      8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk

### ├─sda1   8:1    0   476M  0 part /boot/efi

### ├─sda2   8:2    0  93.1G  0 part /

### ├─sda3   8:3    0 830.5G  0 part /home

### └─sda4   8:4    0   7.5G  0 part [SWAP]

This is my system with a 1Tb hard drive. I usually do:
-500mb is for my EFI Partition
-75Gb and up if you have the space for / the root
-X2 your RAM for Swap for laptops
-Whatever is left for /home - where your data is stored (music, pictures, videos, documents)

I HIGHLY encourage the use of /home as it left me do clean reinstalls without losing my data but keep a backup just incase.